# Using JavaScript/jQuery to decide which hyperlink to use when text is clicked

Tags: javascript, function, coldfusion

I am still new to javascript and am not sure about the syntax or if my thinking is correct. If anyone can provide me advice on how to do this that would be great. Here is what I need to do I have a form where a user can either provide there own credit memo number or the system generates one on its own so I will have two seperate variables.

What I want is that when they click on a link called Create Credit Memo the one of the variables will be sent within the link. If they provide their own number then that number should be sent otherwise the automatic number should be sent. After much time looking through the web this is what I thought would work but I think I am messing up the syntax or doing it completely wrong.

Jave Script - I am sure my syntax is incorrect

```
$('#creditmemolink').click(function(){ 
{

if (&('#creditmemo').is(':defined'))
{   
    var cmnum = document.getElementById('creditmemo').value;
    var ttUrl = "somepage.cfm?creditmemos=#cmnum#&claimid=9988";
    window.open(ttUrl,"_blank");
} else {
    var cmnum = document.getElementById('cmnum').value;
    var ttUrl = "somepage.cfm?creditmemos=#cmnum#&claimid=9988";
    window.open(ttUrl,"_blank");
    return false;
}
}
```

Here is the HTML within the body

```
<div id="DspTxt" style="display:none;" class="txtmedb"> 
 Own Credit Memo: <input type="text" size="25" name="creditmemo" id="creditmemo"   
 class="txtsv" onChange="CreditMemoText()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                        <cfset cmnum = #htmlEditFormat(GETCLAIM.PO_NBR)# & #TimeFormat(NOW(),"hhmm")#>
<cfset cmnum = #cmnum# & #htmlEditFormat(url.claimid)#>
<cfset cmnum = #cmnum# & 'CM'>

      <a href="#" id="credmemolink">Create Credit Memo Test</a>

</div>
```

Any advice on how you would do this would be greatly appreicated. Has stated I am still new to both coldfusion and Java so still learning the best way and correct syntax to use.

Thanks in advance for your assistances on this.

Comment: Since you're new to CF I'll let you know the # are rarely used when you're not specifically outputting something to the screen. They're not needed anywhere in your current code

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
$('#creditmemolink').click(function(){ 
{

if ($('#creditmemo'))
{   
    var num = $('#creditmemo').val();
    //checking if user entered any value
    if(num) {

    } else {
       //executed when user did not provide any input
    }
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your ColdFusion is doing, but I can help with the JavaScript part:

I think what you want to do to your markup is something like:

```
<form id="myForm" action="somepage.cfm" method="GET">
  <input type="hidden" name="claimid" value="9988">
  <input type="hidden" name="creditmemos" id="cmnum">
  <label>
    Own Credit Memo: <input type="text" name="creditmemo" id="creditmemo">
  </label>
  <a href="#" id="credmemolink" data-cmnum="numfromcf">Create Credit Memo Test</a>
</form>
```

And then for your JS:

```
$("#credmemolink").on("click", function(e) {
  var $myForm = $("#myForm"),
      cmnum;

  e.preventDefault();

  if ($("#creditmemo").val() !== "") {
    cmnum = $("#creditmemo").val();
  } else {
    cmnum = $("#credmemolink").data("cmnum");
  }

  $("#cmnum").val(cmnum);
  $myForm.submit();
});
```

This will prevent the default action on the link, then check the value of the field to see if they entered anything.

It will then set a hidden field with the value you need and then submit your form.

Answer (score 0):

Your page will be easier to code and use if you don't combine forms and anchor tags.  Specifically, you don't need an anchor tag and you don't need javascript.  All you need is a form with a textbox and submit button.  Then you can process it like this.

```
<cfscript>
if (len(trim(form.creditmemo))) {
claimId = form.creditmemo;
}
else {
code to generate one
}
etc
```